# Java inheritence - getting this from parent object

Tags: java, android, inheritance

Assuming:

```
class Parent
{
   String getTitle() {
     return "parent";
   } 
   void onResume() {
     System.out.println(getTitle());
   }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    String getTitle() {
       return "Child";
    }
    void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
    }
}
```

and then finally:

```
Child c = new Child();
c.onResume();
```

prints out:

**parent**

Is there anyway to get "Child" printed?  Basically I'm writing an Android app and I have a method called getTitle() that each instance of MyFragment inherits. What I would like to do is automatically when resumed to change the title of the Acitivity by calling the fragment's getTitle() method.

Is this possible?

Comment: Child doesn't extend Parent.

Comment: After the edit it prints "child" :-)

Comment: That's not what I'm getting, it prints Parent for me.

Comment: You should `@Override` the `getTitle()` method

Comment: It prints "Child" for me too.

Comment: With the code you have posted the output will be Child. If it isn't you need ensure all changes are saved, recompile and execute the code again.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code you provided and it works as you expect it to work - it prints 'Child'.

The only issue I have with it is that you don't annotate the methods in `Child` with `@Override` annotation. Thats against the coding standards.

But that annotation is just needed at `Source` level - it is not needed for the runtime. So it should work without it.